# Определить количество отрицательных элементов в строках матрицы

Tags: delphi, массивы, строки, stringgrid

Есть матрица (двумерный массив), который выводится в StringGrid. Нужно для каждой строки матрицы определить количество отрицательных элементов.

Сам пробовал написать вот так, но выдает ошибку "range check error":

```
procedure TForm1.N8Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  d: integer;
begin
  for i:=0 to m do  //счет идет с ноля
  for j:=0 to n do
    x[i,j]:=StrToFloat(StringGrid1.Cells[j,i]);

  m:=strtoint(edit1.Text);
  n:=strtoint(edit2.Text);
  for i:=0 to m do begin
    d:=0;
    for j := 0 to n do
      if x[i,j]<0 then d:=d+1;
    StringGrid2.Cells[0,j]:= FormatFloat('0.',d);
  end;
end;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Чему равно `m` и `n` в первом цикле? Все циклы должны быть до `n - 1` или `m - 1`. Наверное, правильно было бы сделать вот так:

```
procedure TForm1.N8Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    d: integer;
begin
    m := StrToInt(edit1.Text);
    n := StrToInt(edit2.Text);

    for i := 0 to m - 1 do  //счет идет с ноля
        for j := 0 to n - 1 do
            x[i,j] := StrToFloat(StringGrid1.Cells[j,i]);

    for i := 0 to m - 1 do 
    begin
      d := 0;

      for j := 0 to n - 1 do
        if x[i,j] < 0 then 
          d := d + 1;

      StringGrid2.Cells[0,j] := IntToStr(d);
    end;
end;
```

И учтите, что в `edit1.Text` и `edit2.Text` не обязаны быть только числа. Для проверки правильности ввода можно воспользоваться функцией `TryStrToInt` или использовать `StrToIntDef`.

Answer (score 0):

Видимо нужно писать в цикле "for i:=0 to m-1 do" (почти всегда в Делфи верхняя граница с "-1").

Добавка: нужно внимательно следить за границами циклов. Если нижняя граница "0", то для m элементов верхняя граница будет "m-1" и нужно писать "for i:=0 to m-1 do"

Comment: *"почти всегда в Делфи верхняя граница с "-1""* Это не относится к Делфи, а справедливо для всех языков и даже просто перечислений N элементов. Если бы мы перебирали 0..N, то число перебранных элементов было бы N+1 ;-)